# Binary Signals and Combined Price Predicitions

Tags: stochastic-processes, pricing

Consider a binary signal $s(t)\in\{0,1\}$ for times $t\in\mathbb{R^+}$. Also define an asset price $X(t)$. Suppose that the curve,

$E(r(t+h)\space|\space s(t) = 1) = \alpha (1 - e^{-\delta h})$

where $r(t+h)$ is the log return of the asset price measured from time $t$ to time $t+h$ and $E(\cdot)$ denotes the expectation. The intuitive interpretation of the equation above is that upon observing a signal value of $1$, we expect that the return of the asset follows a path starting from $0$ and limiting towards $\alpha$ at a rate determined by the value of $\delta$.

Fix a time $t$ such that $s(t)=1$ and consider two "horizons" $0<h_1 < h_2$. Suppose that $h_1$ time elapses (we are now at time $t+h_1$) and we consider the expectation of $r(t+h_2)$. The value $r(t+h_1)$ is now observed. What can be said of the expectation below as measured from time $t+h_1$?

$E(r(t+h_2)\space |\space r(t+h_1) \land s(t) = 1)$

Intuitively, we would like to know how to "update" our expectation for $r(t+h_2)$ as time elapses and new price (and thus return) observations are made.